# Call to a member function getAllHash

Tags: php, atk4

I'm trying to run the example code available at atk4 website. Downloaded the code, created the models and the generate page. However, when I tried to generate the SQL using http://localhost/demo/atk4-example/?page=generate, I got the following error in apache error log:

```
[Mon Sep 19 21:35:31 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAllHash() on a non-object in /var/www/html/demo/atk4-example/atk4-addons/mvc/Page/SchemaGenerator.php on line 69, referer: http://localhost/demo/atk4-example/?page=generate
```

Here is the Models:

Category.php:

```
class Model_Category extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code = 'category_table';
    public $table_alias = 'ct';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
    }
}
```

Job.php:

```
class Model_Job extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code = 'job_table';
    public $table_alias = 'jt';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('category_id')->refModel('Model_Category');
        $this->addField('type');
        $this->addField('company');
        $this->addField('logo');
        $this->addField('url');
        $this->addField('position');
        $this->addField('location');
        $this->addField('description')->type('text');
        $this->addField('how_to_apply')->type('text');
        $this->addField('is_public')->type('boolean');
        $this->addField('is_activated')->type('boolean');
        $this->addField('email');
        $this->addField('token');
        $this->addField('created_dts')->type('timestamp')->system(true);
        $this->addField('updated_dts')->type('timestamp')->system(true);
        $this->addField('expires_at')->type('date')->system(true);
    }
}
```

page/generate.php:

```
class page_generate extends Page_SchemaGenerator {}
```

Am I missing some path settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Call to a member function getAllHash() on a non-object in
/var/www/html/demo/atk4-example/atk4-addons/mvc/Page/SchemaGenerator.php
on line 69
```

and this line is

```
$res = $this->api->db->getAllHash("desc $table");
```

meaning that `$this->api->db` is not an object.
Take a look at atk4-example/page/dbtest.php. It invokes `$this->api->dbConnect();` which probably sets the api->db property.

Comment: Yes, Make sure you have $this->dbConnect() inside your lib/Frontend.php's init() function.